# CefSharp WinForms V91.1.211 Incorrectly Specified Files Warnings

Tags: cefsharp, .net-4.8

After struggling with many changes and problems due to a recent CefSharp WinForms upgrade to 91.1.211 from V79.1.360, I thought I was all fixed up with [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68307763/1560325) post. :-) However, while at the moment my application is now working, I have developed the following warnings subsequent to adding the `<CefSharpBuildAction>Content</CefSharpBuildAction>` line to the proj file:

*warning MSB3178:
..\packages\CefSharp.Common.91.1.211\buildTransitive..\CefSharp\x86\CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.dll' is incorrectly specified as a file.
..\packages\CefSharp.Common.91.1.211\buildTransitive..\CefSharp\x86\CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe' is incorrectly specified as a file.
warning MSB3187:
..\packages\CefSharp.Common.91.1.211\buildTransitive..\CefSharp\x86\CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll' targets a different processor than the application.*

I have excluded only 3 .pdb files for publishing, eliminating 3 minor warnings referencing security. All target CPU references are set to AnyCPU and Prefer 32-bit is checked, as I believe has been recommended.

Is there anything that can be done to eliminate any of these warnings and clean this up once and for all?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to get rid of the warnings, they should be safe to ignore. You'll likely need to add some extra tags, possibly msbuild as it's an msbuild warning (hence the msb prefix).

Comment: Switching your PlatformTarget to x86 rather than AnyCPU would solve the targets a different processor warning.

Comment: Thanks @amaitland. I'll give your suggestions a try. I appreciate your terrific responsiveness to all of us.  - HB

Comment: Other than the warning in the build log are you experiencing any actual problems?

Comment: No, sir -- all else is working fine.

Comment: I believe it's safe to ignore. Quick search suggests there is no way to disable the warning https://stackoverflow.com/a/39135332/4583726